# Hokkien `綴` vs. `共`: compare and contrast

Tags: topolect, hokkien

According to [my reference](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/index.html), both `綴` (tuè/tè) and `共` (kā) can translate from Hokkien (alias Min Nan) to `跟`. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4):

The word tuè/tè in Taiwanese Hokkien is used in contexts where 跟 in Mandarin more explicitly refers to the action of "following"; in the 台灣閩南語常用詞辭典 you can find the word `kin-tuè/kun-tè`, as written `跟綴`. In the [台文/華文線頂辭典](http://goo.gl/umekoz), a fuller list of words with `綴` can be found. Perhaps most indicative of its use is the Taiwanese Hokkien equivalent of `跟得上`, which is `綴會著 tòe/tè-ē-tio̍h`.

The function of `共 kā` is more grammatical, and often marks an "additional valency" as expressed on page 23 of [*Written Taiwanese*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ouhzKI8rkZkC); in practice this means another verb must follow `共 + noun phrase` at some point, for example in that most famous of Hokkien utterances `我共你講`.